# Control iOs & Android Softkeyboard with javascript or native HTML

Tags: javascript, ios, android-softkeyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

Is there any solution to control the softkeyboards from iOs & Android with Javascript or HTML ?

My Problem is that i have to remove the Button "Return, Open and "Next"" when iOs & Android user focused an input.

It is very important that they dont have the possibility to click these Buttons to get to the next input field.

Comment: This is not possible !!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to change the behaviour of softkeyboards using JS. You can do it via native but with JS, it seems not possible.

Comment: via native ? Tell me more.